# Prove or disprove: given a unitary $U$ with elements $e_{mn}$ such that for $m\ne n$, either $e_{mn}=0$ or $e_{nm}=0$, then $U$ is diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am doing research on [configuring universal multi-port interferometers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.00458), and I have a lemma which I believe to be true, but I'm having trouble proving (or disproving) it. Any help would be appreciated!

**Lemma:** Consider a unitary matrix $U\in\mathrm{U}(N)$ with elements $e_{mn}$. If for every $m\ne n$, either $e_{mn}=0$ or $e_{nm}=0$, then $U$ is diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

This is false; a counterexample is $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ or more generally any nontrivial permutation matrix with no $2$-cycles.

Comment: Ah, that's a silly oversight on my part. The lemma as stated is clearly false, but I think there might still be something to it, since this class of matrices seems pretty restrictive. Is it possible that $U$ must expressible as a product of a diagonal matrix of $e^{i\phi}$ and a permutation matrix?

Comment: No; for instance, you could consider a block matrix you get by replacing each $1$ in a permutation matrix with some unitary matrix.  If you replace each $1$ in my example above with a $2\times 2$ unitary with all nonzero entries, the resulting $6\times 6$ unitary satisfies your condition  but is not a product of a diagonal matrix and a permutation matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As one final question, suppose you have a unitary matrix $U$ and you can constrain N(N-1)/2 off-diagonal elements of the matrix to be zero. Do you know of any placement of the zeros other than upper/lower triangular that will force $U$ to be diagonal?

Comment: Well, more generally the zeroes could be triangular with respect to any ordering of the standard basis.  There may also be some minor modifications that still work; for instance, if the zeroes make $U$ upper triangular except for one single entry, I think that would still force it to be diagonal.